# Configuring a cisco switch for ip division

Tags: networking, ip, console

I have been provided a single copper cat6 cable from my isp with subnet 28. So they provided me 12 public ip for usage now I have a new layer 3 cisco switch. So now I want to set this switch such that when I insert this isp copper cable to one of the ports I can use all of the remaining 23 ports in a way such that if I connect any of ports to my computer this can set to use any of those 12 public ips.

However, when I set this cable to use in layer 2 switch this scenarion worked perfectly ok. But not in layer3 switch.

So can anyone tell me how can I configure this layer 3 cisco switch as all port work as bridge to the incoming port.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Ubuntu!! But /28 mask you can make:

- One subnet /28 (use as L2 switch) with 14 usable IPs
- Two subnets /29 with with 6 usable IPs
- Four subnets /30 with with 2 usable IPs

Pick your poison

Comment: Yes I know it has nothing to do with ubuntu. But if anyone can help me with configuring this switch.